# EF Core: Generic StartsWith() Expression not Translatable

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to build kind of a generic "StartsWith" Expression in EF Core 3.1.5.
The managed entity looks like this:

```cs
public class MyEntity
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key] // key just for the sake of having a key defined, not relevant for the question
    public string TopLevelString { get; set; }

    public AnotherEntity OtherEntity { get; set; }
}
public class AnotherEntity
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]  // key just for the sake of having a key defined, not relevant for the question
    public string NestedString { get; set; }
}
```

I put it into a context like this:

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) {}
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=sqlitedemo.db");
}
```

And try to use this context within a test class:

```cs
public partial class MyTestClass // this part is just to make the example 100% reproducable
{ 
    // define some minimal examples to work with
    private List<MyEntity> testExampleList = new List<MyEntity>()
    {
        new MyEntity()
        {
            TopLevelString = "ABC",
            OtherEntity = new AnotherEntity(){NestedString = "ABC"}
        },
        new MyEntity()
        {
            TopLevelString = "XYZ",
            OtherEntity = new AnotherEntity(){NestedString = "XYZ"}
        }
    };

    MyDbContext context;
    public MyTestClass()
    {
        // set up database
        var options = new DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>();
        this.context = new MyDbContext(options);
        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // add examples from above list
        this.context.MyEntities.AddRange(testExampleList);
        this.context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here's the thing I'd like to do as a plain Where filter:

```cs
public partial class MyTestClass // this part works as expected and is just used to illustrate the purpose of below code
{ 
    [Fact]
    public void TestFilteringWithoutOwnExpression()
    {
        Assert.Equal(1, context.MyEntities.Where(x => x.TopLevelString.StartsWith("A")).Count()); // works fine
        Assert.Equal(1, context.MyEntities.Where(x => x.OtherEntity.NestedString.StartsWith("A")).Count()); // works, too
    }
}
```

Since there's some other magic supposed to happen before the actual where clause is applied, I tried to wrap it into an own expression like this:

```cs
public partial class MyTestClass // this part does not work and I don' know why
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestFilteringWithExpression()
    {
        Assert.Equal(1, context.MyEntities.MyWhere<MyEntity>(x => x.TopLevelString, "A").Count());
        Assert.Equal(1, context.MyEntities.MyWhere<MyEntity>(x => x.OtherEntity.NestedString, "A").Count());
    }
}
```

with `MyWhere` being defined in an extension class:

```cs
public static class IQueryableExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> MyWhere<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> query, Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> stringSelector, string searchString)
    {
        ParameterExpression entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), stringSelector.Parameters.First().Name);
        MemberExpression memberExpr = (MemberExpression)(stringSelector.Body);
        var searchConstant = Expression.Constant(searchString, typeof(string));

        var filterExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
                                         Expression.Call(
                                            memberExpr,
                                            typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.StartsWith), new Type[] { typeof(string) }),
                                            searchConstant),
                                         entityParameter);
        query = query.Where(filterExpression);
        return query;
    }
}
```

I saw similar examples where instead of a MemberExpression a PropertyExpression is being used, but this failed for my as soon as I tried to access not only `MyEntity.TopLevelString` but the nested `MyEntity.AnotherEntity.NestedString`.

The code fails with an InvalidOperationException:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(m => x.TopLevelString != null && "A" != null && x.TopLevelString.StartsWith("A"))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation...+

How do I setup a generic and translatable StartsWith Expression?

Comment: Remove `"A" != null`

Comment: _Remove "A" != null_ It's autogenerated by EF. I didn't write it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem is not related to `StartsWith`. If you check the exception `DbSet .Where(m => x.TopLevelString != null && "A" != null && x.TopLevelString.StartsWith("A")` starts with `m =>` but inside uses `x` this is caused by  `ParameterExpression entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), stringSelector.Parameters.First().Name);` line. You use that parameter name to generate another parameter but they are not the same.

There are 2 solutions for that.

1. Is to use parameter directly and extend your expression on it
2. Rewrite your member expression with the newly created parameter which is redundant.

So basically this will solve your issue :

```
ParameterExpression entityParameter =  stringSelector.Parameters.First();
```

If you try your extension method on a collection like `List<T>` you would get an error like below:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'variable 'x' of type 'ExpressionTest.MyEntity' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'

Comment: Damn...How did I missed that.